# TCP связь с сервером

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-server-2012

Имеется обычный и серверный клиент для многопользовательского чата(простой и в консоли), также есть ВДС(сервер) с установленной на нем Windows Server 2012.
При проверке работы чата(серверного и обычного) на локалке работает нормально, но если запустить серверный клиент на ВДС, то я уже не могу к нему подключиться (не проходит `TCPclient.Connect(IP,PORT)`).

Comment: Не забывайте о красоте русского языка ;)

Comment: Разбирайтесь с портами. Какие порты закрыты на VDS, какие у вас на рабочей машине.

Comment: +включить сетевое обнаружение, брендмауэр и антивирь контроллят порты, например.